# OrientDb failed to cast index of composite type

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, orientdb

I was using OrientDb for running multiple integration tests. However, at some point during the execution OrientDB failed to use index of OType.String

```
{db=hit} Error on using index UserEntity.name in query 'SELECT FROM UserEntity WHERE name LUCENE 'ivan*''. Probably you need to rebuild indexes. Now executing query using cluster scan
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.orientechnologies.lucene.collections.OFullTextCompositeKey cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at com.orientechnologies.common.serialization.types.OStringSerializer.preprocess(OStringSerializer.java:32)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.sbtree.local.OSBTree.get(OSBTree.java:172)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.engine.OSBTreeIndexEngine.get(OSBTreeIndexEngine.java:212)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexMultiValues.get(OIndexMultiValues.java:72)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexMultiValues.get(OIndexMultiValues.java:53)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexAbstractDelegate.get(OIndexAbstractDelegate.java:57)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexTxAwareMultiValue.get(OIndexTxAwareMultiValue.java:272)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexTxAwareMultiValue.get(OIndexTxAwareMultiValue.java:40)
at com.orientechnologies.lucene.operator.OLuceneTextOperator.executeIndexQuery(OLuceneTextOperator.java:59)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.searchForIndexes(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:1929)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.searchInClasses(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:922)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLResultsetAbstract.assignTarget(OCommandExecutorSQLResultsetAbstract.java:199)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.assignTarget(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:493)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.executeSearch(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:475)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:446)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:90)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.executeCommand(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1433)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.command(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1406)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLQuery.run(OSQLQuery.java:72)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLSynchQuery.run(OSQLSynchQuery.java:85)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.query.OQueryAbstract.execute(OQueryAbstract.java:33)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.filter.OSQLFilterCondition.evaluate(OSQLFilterCondition.java:83)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.filter.OSQLFilterCondition.evaluate(OSQLFilterCondition.java:329)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.filter.OSQLFilterCondition.evaluate(OSQLFilterCondition.java:76)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.filter.OSQLFilter.evaluate(OSQLFilter.java:100)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLResultsetAbstract.evaluateRecord(OCommandExecutorSQLResultsetAbstract.java:401)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLResultsetAbstract.filter(OCommandExecutorSQLResultsetAbstract.java:391)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.executeSearchRecord(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:558)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.fetchFromTarget(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:1480)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.executeSearch(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:488)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:446)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:90)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.executeCommand(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1433)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.command(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1406)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLQuery.run(OSQLQuery.java:72)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLSynchQuery.run(OSQLSynchQuery.java:85)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.query.OQueryAbstract.execute(OQueryAbstract.java:33)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.command(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:1317)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.executeRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:399)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.execute(OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.java:223)
at com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:77)
```

I tried to rebuild index. But, I still got IllegalArgumentException

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: targetGen=2 was never returned by the ReferenceManager instance (current gen=1)
```

Comment: Hi, you can try creating new index with same settings but different name.

Comment: @OleksandrGubchenko, Thank you. That does not work either because OrientDb is trying to cast wrong index type anyway.

Comment: Is it possible for you to send DB for analysis to the OrientDB company ?

Comment: How many indexes did you create on the property UserEntity.name?

Comment: @wolf4ood, there are two indexes of different types: normal and fts